# Coloring the 1 x n field

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I have a field of 1 x n size. I need to color it using: red, orange, green, blue. Also, I can color red only even amount of blocks, and orange only odd amount of blocks.

Finally I need to find a generating function describing how many combinations of different colors I can use.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you need to use each colour at least once? For red, assuming the answer to the previous question is false, is $0$ an even number for you?

Comment: Even for red and odd for orange is the only requirement, so I guess I don't need to use each color at least once.

Comment: Does order matter?  You'ved asked for the number of combinations of different colours, but do you properly mean permutations? Or are you looking at the number of ways to pick $n$ blocks within these four colours?

Comment: The order doesn't matter.

Comment: And yes, as you've said - I'm looking at the number of ways to pick n blocks withing these colors.

Comment: Order doesn't matter doesn't make sense if the problem is about coloring. Are you coming up with these problems on your own, or are you getting them from somewhere? (The previous problem about blocks you also too an odd view that would be different for any real problem from a book.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How doesn't it make sense? It seems to me like an [unordered set containing repetition](http://www.mathematics-online.org/kurse/kurs9/seite26.html).

Comment: Because the problem is about "coloring," and we don't color un-ordered. The problem explicitly mentions coloring an $1\times n$ rectangle. @ZettaSuro

Comment: @ZettaSuro I don't mean it doesn't make mathematical sense, but rather that it doesn't make pedagogical sense to ask the question this way. See the OPs previous question, where he asks a question with a ton of colors, but then he states in comments that the colors aren't important to the answer. It's hard to tell, without knowing where OP is getting the problems, whether he is just confused or he is correctly reflecting an actual question. For all we know, he is making the problems up on his own. But if they are problems from a book or class, then I strongly suspect he is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If order doesn’t matter, you’re looking at partitions of $n$ into four parts labelled red, orange, green, and blue, where any of the parts except the orange part can be empty, the red part must be even, and the orange part must be odd. Look at the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product

$$\begin{align*}
&\underbrace{(1+x^2+x^4+\ldots)}_{\text{red}}\underbrace{(x+x^3+x^5+\ldots)}_{\text{orange}}\underbrace{(1+x+x^2+\ldots)}_{\text{green}}\underbrace{(1+x+x^2+\ldots)}_{\text{blue}}=\\\\
&\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}x^{2n}\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}x^{2n+1}\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

All of these summations have simple generating functions.

Answer (score 0):

Brian M. Scott's answer gets ugly when asking for explicit coefficients...

You are classifying sequences into (subindex is length):

- Even red, even orange ($a_n$, with $a_0 = 1$)
- Even red, odd orange  ($b_n$, with $b_0 = 0$)
- Odd red, even orange  ($c_n$, with $c_0 = 0$)
- Odd red, odd orange   ($d_n$, with $d_0 = 0$)

You can set up recurrences, by noting that to get the $a_{n + 1}$ even/even secuences you can start with the $a_n$ even/even and add green or blue ($2 a_n$ ways) or start with even/odd and add orange ($b_n$ ways) or odd/even and add red ($c_n$ ways). Completing this:
$$
\begin{align*}
a_{n + 1} &= 2 a_n + b_n + c_n \\
b_{n + 1} &= a_n + 2 b_n + d_n \\
c_{n + 1} &= a_n + 2 c_n + d_n \\
d_{n + 1} &= b_n + c_n + 2 d_n
\end{align*}
$$ 
Define generating functions $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$ and so on; multiply the recurrences by $z^n$ and add over $n \ge 0$ to get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} &= 2 A(z) + B(z) + C(z) \\
\frac{B(z) - b_0}{z} &= A(z) + 2 B(z) + D(z) \\
\frac{C(z) - c_0}{z} &= A(z) + 2 C(z) + D(z) \\
\frac{D(z) - d_0}{z} &= B(z) + C(z) + 2 D(z)
\end{align*}
$$
Solve this linear system of equations for $B(z)$:
$$
B(z) = \frac{z}{1 - 4 z}
     = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 4 z} - \frac{1}{4}
$$
You can read the coefficients from the geometric series (the $[n = 0]$ is Iverson's bracket, $1$ if $n = 0$ and 0 otherwise):
$$
b_n = 4^{n - 1} - \frac{1}{4} [n = 0]
$$
I.e, $b_n = \langle 0, 1, 4, 16, \ldots \rangle$